# 3 bolt exercise bike saddle adapter in the UK

Tags: saddle, seatpost, uk, stationary-bike

The saddle currently fitted to my exercise bike is attached to a fixed plate with 3 bolts on it, I can't find any adapters to fit more traditional saddles (rails/posts) that are available in the UK. The current saddle is criminally uncomfortable and I would really like to replace it with a more traditional saddle designed for comfort.

My current bike:
https://www.argos.co.uk/product/4026004
"Roger Black Gold Magnetic Exercise Bike"

Adapter style that I need(not available in the UK and they don't ship outside of US/Canada.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/FitDesk-Saddle-Adapter-Universal/dp/B00M24K97G

[image]

Does anyone know of any UK based company/bike shop that could provide an appropriate adapter for this style of fitting by any chance?

This is my last resort before I have to go out and buy a new bike.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Don't you know a person with welding abilities?

Comment: I don't unfortunately.

Comment: I got my bike frame welded by a pro welder - the cost was surprisingly minimal.    Look for an outfit that does roll-cages.  The trick is to do everything else yourself, like clean the parts and show exactly what you want done.

Comment: Did you find a solution? we are having the same problem...

Comment: Why not replace the post?

Comment: Based on the photo on your link, this exercise bike uses a normal bicycle saddle with a clamp around a vertical post.  Consider please adding a photo of what you have now, and describe what's wrong with it.

Comment: Some close-up pictures of the saddle mounting arrangement would be helpful.